# How do I synchronize two processes in C++ (Windows)?

Tags: c++, winapi, process, synchronization

Parent process launches a child process by invoking CreateProcess() method which returns immediately even before the child process is initialized. How do I make the parent process wait until the Child process got initialized and started executing? WaitForSingleObject() call makes the parent process to wait until the child thread terminates or until timeout.

Is there any similar method which makes the parent process to wait until the child process is intialized?

Comment: What *precisely* do you mean by "initialized"?

Comment: By Initialized, I mean the child process having started its execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [create a named event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx) in WinAPI in the parent process and set it to unsignalled state. Call WaitForSingleObject on the event handle. Then in the child process you can open event by name and signal it (call [SetEvent()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211(v=vs.85).aspx)) after the child process is initialized.

Comment: I wonder, why Eralp's answer has no upvotes, at least in c# join is perhaps the most common way, if I remember correctly, so why not use it on c++ ?

Comment: @icbytes, the question is about synchronization between processes, not about synchronization of threads within 1 process.

Comment: Ehm, sorry for that. Right. Then signals are the common stuff.

Comment: What do you mean by signals? The question is about Windows platform.

Comment: Yes, I chose this, because of the "unsignalled" state. Some years ago I wrote some small tool for linux, where I also spawn a child process, and there I was reading about signals, when I remember correctly.

Comment: This is the correct general solution without knowing exactly what _"until the child got initialized"_ means. For a more specialized situation, Win32 provides the dedicated function [WaitForInputIdle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms687022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Damon: Except, [WaitForInputIdle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022.aspx) is essentially useless (or at least **very** easy to get wrong): [WaitForInputIdle waits for any thread, which might not be the thread you care about](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/26/9985422.aspx).

Comment: Note that the event name has to be unique.  (What if two copies of the parent process are running?)   The easiest way to do this is to include the child's process ID in the name, though you have to be a bit careful to make sure your code works properly regardless of whether the child or the parent creates the event object.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: That's actually easily solved: create the event in the parent before you create the child process, create a GUID for the event name, pass the GUID to the child process on startup. Fixes both the uniqueness and the creation order.

Comment: @MSalters: that's another option, yes.  IMO, it's usually easier to use the child process ID, as it saves you the hassle of getting the GUID to the child.  Matter of taste I suppose.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: The child PID exists only after the child process is started, which causes the event creation race condition. Getting the GUID to the child process is simple, just pass it on the command line.

Comment: @MSalters: The race is easily solved by creating the child with the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag. The child PID exists, after the process object has been **created**. The primary thread doesn't have to be **started** to get a PID.

Comment: On second thoughts, there's a race condition different than the one I was thinking of originally - the child process might exit before the parent process opens the event.  @IInspectable's suggestion deals with that as well as with the more obvious one.  But if you don't hate parsing the command line as much as I do, that's a perfectly good solution too.

Comment: Thank you Serge !! I have created a named event using CreateEvent in the parent process and set it to unsignalled state. I did a WaitForSingleObject on this event handle. Then in the child process I open the event by name and signal it by call SetEvent() after the child process is initialized. This solution has worked.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions !!

Comment: @Vanathi, if the solution works, you should accept the answer at Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Vanathi: You should probably [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025.aspx) on both the event as well as the child process handle. That way you don't deadlock, when the child process fails to call `SetEvent` (e.g. because it crashed).

Comment: @ IInspectable: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try it out. In my case, calling WaitForSingleObject on the event object with timeout value passed as an argument, deadlock can be avoided. The parent process wakes up from waiting state once the timeout criteria is met (in case the child process crashes).

Answer (score -2):

If you are using threads, one of the simpliest way to make parent thread wait until the child finishes is using .join() function. In the parent process's end use

```
child.join();
```

Comment: The question is about synchronization between processes, not about synchronization of threads within 1 process